# MapBox Geolocating by IP Address

Tags: geolocation, maps, mapbox

I'm currently implementing MapBox and i need to geolocate based on two options:

- Zip-Code
- Ip-Addresses

I tried Geolocating by zipcode. I think it is possible, but it will be great if someone is completely certain.

For Ip Address, I'm still trying to find if this is possible with MapBox, or i will require an external web tool to get approximate location data where i can inject it into MapBox ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geolocation via zip codes are currently not available with Mapbox's geocoder, however there are some major updates to mapbox's geocoder scheduled to be released within the coming months. A post on Mapbox's blog noted geocoder updates and Mapbox Directions will be released [early 2014.](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/osrm-shared-memory/)

Comment: Hi @geraldarthur 

Geolocating via zipcode is indeed available by doing:

`map.geocoder.query( '33187' , function(err, data){....}`

Definitively is not available by ip-address. I used another service for Geolocating by Ip Address.

Thanks for your reply.